# Mysql conecta mas não exibe as chaves

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Bom dia

meu codigo retorna esse erro

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /home2/minhap26/public_html/paginas/listas.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home2/minhap26/public_html/alimentacao/adegas.php(92): include() #1 {main} thrown in /home2/minhap26/public_html/paginas/listas.php on line 8

Abaixo o código original sem as modificações.

---

```
include('../editar/adm_conexao.php'); // conect BD

$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE ATIVE_LISTA = 'S' ORDER BY RAND()"; 
// tabela empresa, sinalizadas com S, em ordem aleatória na lista

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conexao)
or die($sql . '<br/>' . mysql_error($conexao) ) ;     
$row = mysql_num_rows($result); 

//die($sql);

if($row== 0){
echo '';}

$conexao->close();

// ----------------------------------

for($i=0 ; $i < $row; $i++);
{
  
$nome = mysql_result($resultado,$i,'nome');
$telefone = mysql_result($resultado,$i,'telefone');

    echo "<h2>$nome</h2>";
    echo "<h2>$telefone</h2>";  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro ponto a ser observado é que o driver mysql é obsoleto, o correto é utilizar mysqli ou PDO, vou lhe mostrar uma conexão PDO,
no seu arquivo **conexao.php** coloque:

```
try {
    $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=crudsimples", "root", "123456");
    $conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conexao->exec("set names utf8");
} catch (PDOException $erro) {
    echo "Erro na conexão:" . $erro->getMessage();
}
```

e em sua consulta pode-se colocar:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbestado";
  $resultado = $conexao->query($sql)->fetchAll();

foreach($resultado as $item){
 echo "<p>Nome: ".$item['nome']."<br>";
 echo "<p>Nome: ".$item['telefone']."<br>";
}
```

Obs.: o $item['algumacoisa'] corresponde ao nome da coluna de sua tabela

Comment: Curso de PDO completo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C92cScfsFW4&list=PLYGFJHWj9BYqSXzSfHGd46yipCrkjC8AD

Comment: Crud PDO completo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYFIa8oO08Y&list=PLbnAsJ6zliduRkxrkVjB_acpNt9jN68w9&index=6   OBS: Aula 1 até a 10

Comment: Mais sobre PHP moderno: http://br.phptherightway.com/

Comment: Muito obrigado Thalles. Consegui. Vou fazer algumas adaptações no código. Grande abraço.